# Highcharts: Double side's legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to display company's balance sheet with Highcharts.

[image: sample]

I want to put legend on left side and right side like this.

I couldn't not find the way to do that.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using this approach:

Set appropriate legend options:

```
legend: {
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    itemMarginBottom: 15,
    width: 200,
    padding: 0
}
```

Then, the legend will be rendered in two columns. Loop through chart series in `render` event callback and translate each legend element that has translateX property greater than 0 to another side of the chart. Note that chart margins (left and right) should be set. Check the code and demo posted below.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    marginLeft: 150,
    marginRight: 100,
    spacingLeft: 10,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          offsetLeft = 20,
          element,
          itemX,
          translateX,
          translateY;

        chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
          element = series.legendItem.parentGroup;
          translateY = element.translateY;

          if (element.translateX > 0) {
            translateX = chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft + offsetLeft;

            element.translate(translateX, translateY);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    itemMarginBottom: 15,
    width: 200,
    padding: 0
  },
  series: [
    { data: [6, 4, 2], name: 'First' },
    { data: [7, 3, 2], name: 'Second' },
    { data: [9, 4, 8], name: 'Third' },
    { data: [1, 2, 6], name: 'Fourth' },
    { data: [4, 6, 4], name: 'Fifth' },
    { data: [1, 2, 7], name: 'Sixth' },
    { data: [4, 2, 5], name: 'Seventh' },
    { data: [8, 3, 2], name: 'Eighth' },
    { data: [4, 5, 6], name: 'Ninth' },
    { data: [6, 4, 2], name: 'First' },
    { data: [7, 3, 2], name: 'Second' },
    { data: [9, 4, 8], name: 'Third' },
    { data: [1, 2, 6], name: 'Fourth' },
    { data: [4, 6, 4], name: 'Fifth' },
    { data: [1, 2, 7], name: 'Sixth' },
    { data: [4, 2, 5], name: 'Seventh' },
    { data: [8, 3, 2], name: 'Eighth' },
    { data: [4, 5, 6], name: 'Ninth' }
  ]
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

#### API reference

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight

Comment: Amazing! awesome solution! Thank you so much. This is what I wanted and couldn't do...